# WiFi has disappeared on Lubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: wifi, network-interface, macintosh, lubuntu, lshw

I have been running Lubuntu on my old late 2008 Macbook successfully for a couple of years. This week, the WiFi has suddenly stopped working. Running `lshw`, `lsusb` and `lspci` shows no sign of the WiFi interface at all.

I've run a full software update over ethernet, and restarted the system a couple of times, but to no avail.

The fault appeared from one day to the next, and did not follow a software update or any other obvious change to the system. I'm leaning towards a hardware fault currently (it is a 15yo laptop, after all), but is there anything else I can do to try and diagnose/fix this fault?

Comment: You can, if accessible, open it and re-seat the WiFi card.

Comment: Check the system logs, you might be able to find out what happened, they usually span at least a week. If you cannot do it right away, make a copy to have them available later.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - I unfortunately was too slow to get at anything useful on the system logs. Everything seemed to point to a hardware issue, so I opened it up and reseated the WiFi card. This didn't fix it, so I think it's likely a more serious hardware fault (dead card/connection/similar). Perhaps to be expected from a 15 year old laptop!